# Proc in rails with INOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures

Mysql2::Error: OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine database_name.proc_name is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

So, I'm calling a proc basically by just doing

```
connection = Mysql2::Client.new(config)
result = connection.query('call proc_name(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)')
```

The proc has 5 arguments, the first 2 are IN and the last 3 are INOUT.  Now, I think it's complaining because it wants the INOUT's to be variables it can assign to /change the value of.

So, since my connection.query is calling a string (that get's sanitized beforehand), is there a different method to call the proc, so that the INOUT's will work?

Answer (score 0):

So, the mysql should look like this:

```
@variable1=1;
call proc_name( @variable1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
select @variable1;
```

(assuming that the first variable is the only INOUT )

basically each INOUT variable needs to be defined, then used as the arg, and selected, right?